# what should be login flow to prevent relogin on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I've created a simple web application,

The flow is :  Login Page --(onlogin)--> Home Page ---(onlogout)--> Login Page.

But after user logs out, if you press the back button, and refresh the page, again it logs you in, as the browser resends the login data.

I am using Java Servlets.
When user logs in, a session variable is set, with a key of userid, and session is invalidated on logout.

I thought of storing the login timestamp in database, and if user logs in back with old timestamp( which happens by resend on page refresh), it becomes an invalid login attempt. 
But the database modification is not in my hands.

Is there any better solution ?

Comment: Have you invalidate the session when logging out ? I guess not

Comment: it could be caused by the server session id is changing. I also experience the same

Comment: after logout,go back...and refresh the page and check if you are logged in..

Comment: yeah, i'm invalidating the session, but on page refresh, it again creates a new valid session.
Santino : yes it is logging in

Answer (score 0):

change your flow
Login Page --(onlogin)--> Home Page ---(onlogout)--> Login Page.
to

**Login Page --(onlogin)-->(proccess method)--then redirect to---> Home Page ---(onlogout)--> Login Page.**

data is resending after refresh because just after login you redirect to home page., and i am sure if you normal refreshs when you are in session and home page it will surely resend data.